# Having a trouble with QuickSort

Tags: sorting, quicksort

I have an array.

```
   7,5,4,6,9,8
```

Pivot is the first element which is 7. So, the left cursor is 5 and right cursor is 8. After comparison between pivot and (left and right cursor), both cursor met at 6. So, the left cursor is at 6 and the right cursor is at 6. I am not sure what should I do after this step. Should I swap 6 with pivot,7 or should I swap 4 with pivot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should swap 6 with the pivot 7. 
The algorithm states that once the right cursor is at the same position or farther left than the left cursor (the left cursor passed the right cursor), it should stop iterating. In this case, they both point to 6 as you correctly showed. Once the cursors stop iterating, you are supposed to swap the pivot with the element that the **right cursor** is pointing to, which is 6 in this case.

So, 7 is now the partition element in the array, and the next step is to recursively call quicksort on the elements to the right of 7, and the elements to the left of 7. As you can see, all the elements to the right are >7, and all the elements to the left are <7. Continue the same process you laid out above and the array will be sorted.